# Java Converting from String to int/dbl with Buffered Reader

Tags: java, string, switch-statement, bufferedreader

I am using buffered reader to read variables from a csv and calculate new variables. In this case `REG` is an `int` and `DEP` is a `double`.

I need to make my calculation based on the value of `REG`. But it seems importing the String variable won't allow me to make the calculation.

```
public class CalcTest {

    static String REG;
    static String DEP;
    static String TEMP;

public static void main(String[] args) {


    String csvFile = "M:\\MandNDrives\\mwallace\\JAVA for NEMS\\EORModule\\NEMSEORDBEX1.csv";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";

    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        br.readLine();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            String [] reservoir = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

            REG = reservoir[3];
            DEP = reservoir[4];      

        }
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    }catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
//calculate variables not found in WLOIL
public void varCalc(){

    switch (REG){
        case 1: TEMP = 0.107*DEP+61.065; break;
        case 2: TEMP = 0.0123*DEP+80.302; break;

    }
    System.out.println(TEMP);
```

Comment: If `REG` is an `int` and `DEP` is a `double`, why don't you declare them as so? There are methods to parse `String` values into `int` and `double` values.

Comment: hint hint... Integer.valueOf(String)  Double.valueOf(String)

Comment: I tried to declare them as such, but importing the 'String [] reservoir' values from the csv file is incompatible. I tried 'REG = Integer.valueOf(reservoir [3]);' but I got the same "cannot convert String to integer" error

Comment: I would take a look at what it is pulling out as the string value for reservoir[3] per say.  Make sure that it is a value that can be parsed out to an int.  Make sure it's you don't have any extra characters that are causing errors.

Comment: I think you should be using `Integer.parseInt()` rather than `Integer.valueOf()`... Misread gtgaxiola's comment. `valueOf()` isn't right.

Comment: `String [] reservoir = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
                
 REG = Integer.parseInt(reservoir[3]);` still returns the "incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String" error

Comment: You can't just do a line split on a CSV row.  There could be commas inside of quoted text values.  Either find a CSV library, or write your own text splitter than takes into account quoted text fields.

Comment: Does that error occur when REG is declared as `int` and you try `REG = Integer.parseInt(reservoir[3])`?